# Angularjs code refactoring

Tags: angularjs, refactoring

I have my angularjs project, in this I have this code block, which is fired depending upon the dropdown selection. In this code the **if** and **else** part is mostly similar, I want to refactor the code so that the code is not repeated.

```
 if (1 === $scope.form.type) {
    response = $scope.resource.searchItemSalesInfo(params.get, params.post,function(response, headers) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(row, id) {
            response[id].prod_info = row.alias + ' (' + row.final_product_id + ') ';
        });
        $scope.totalCount = headers('x-total-count');
    });
} else {
    response = $scope.resource.searchOrderSalesInfo(params.get, params.post,function(response, headers) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(row, id) {
            response[id].prod_info = row.alias + ' (' + row.final_product_id + ') ';
        });
        $scope.totalCount = headers('x-total-count');
    });
}
```

I tried to take the common functionality out in the below manner, but then the code does not works, and it breaks the functionality.

```
$scope.callresource = function(resourcename){
    response = $scope.resource.resourcename(params.get, params.post,function(response, headers) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(row, id) {
            response[id].prod_info = row.alias + ' (' + row.final_product_id + ') ';
        });
        $scope.totalCount = headers('x-total-count');
    });
}



   if (1 === $scope.form.type) {
        $scope.callresource(searchItemSalesInfo);
    } else {    

$scope.callresource(searchOrderSalesInfo);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried calling it with `$scope.resource[resourcename](...)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to my other reply, you could pass a reference to the function that you want to be executed in `$scope.callresource` ... in other words **a callback function**

I believe this is the more scalable approach.

```
$scope.callresource = function(resourceCallbackFunction){
    response = resourceCallbackFunction(params.get, params.post,function(response, headers) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(row, id) {
            response[id].prod_info = row.alias + ' (' + row.final_product_id + ') ';
        });
        $scope.totalCount = headers('x-total-count');
    });
}


if (1 === $scope.form.type) {
    $scope.callresource($scope.resource.searchItemSalesInfo);
} else {    
    $scope.callresource($scope.resource.searchOrderSalesInfo);
}
```

Comment: I will try this one, I think this might work. Will update you

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the function using this syntax `$scope.resource.resourcename` because this syntax is telling JS to execute a function called `resourcename`.

Instead, try using the bracket notation:

`$scope.resource[resourcename](..)`

Also, when invoking the `$scope.callresource` function, pass the arguments as strings, because `searchItemSalesInfo` and `searchOrderSalesInfo` currently JS is trying to find them as variables.

`$scope.callresource('searchItemSalesInfo');`

Your code would look like this:

```
$scope.callresource = function(resourcename){
    response = $scope.resource[resourcename](params.get, params.post,function(response, headers) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(row, id) {
            response[id].prod_info = row.alias + ' (' + row.final_product_id + ') ';
        });
        $scope.totalCount = headers('x-total-count');
    });
}


if (1 === $scope.form.type) {
    $scope.callresource('searchItemSalesInfo');
} else {    
    $scope.callresource('searchOrderSalesInfo');
}
```